# How can I randomly order my elements in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to randomly order widgets that will appear in a column.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){    return Column(
  children: [
    Question(
      questions[questionIndex]['singular'],
    ),
    ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>).map((answer) {
      return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text']);
    }).toList()
  ],
);
}
```

I want to shuffle the part of the widget that starts `...(questions[questionIndex]...` but when I do this bu adding `.shuffle()` to the list to get this error `Spread elements in list or set literals must implement 'Iterable'.` I've also tried moving the shuffling to an initState method but then the app builds but I see errors on the screen when I run the app. (`NoSuchMethodError: 'shuffle'`). Does anyone know how I can order this list of widgets randomly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var answers = (questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>);
    answers.shuffle();
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['singular'],
        ),
        ...answers
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text']);
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but I also get an error when I do this. The IDE underlines ...answers and says 'This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.' and, when I do a reload, the terminal says 'Error: The method 'map' isn't defined for the class 'void''.

Comment: ``shuffle()`` method returns void !

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @Eind997

Answer (score 1):

Use the [shuffle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/shuffle.html) method to shuffle/randomise the list:

```
...((questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)..shuffle())
```

**Complete code:**

```
Column(
  children: [
    Question(
      questions[questionIndex]['singular'],
    ),
    ...((questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
          ..shuffle())
        .map((answer) {
      return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text']);
    }).toList()
  ],
)
```